# Do Asynchronous Loggers really help in performance?

Tags: c++, logging, locking

We know that synchronous logging, writes the log message to the file and then continues to the program execution. Asynchronous loggers queues the log messages and writes them in a separate thread. I'm starting to implement Log4CPlus in my Project and couple of things came to my mind.

I can't initialize more LogObjects, because that will open more file handles and we don't need that. (I Know we should use Feature based logging objects, example for UploadLogObj,DownloadLogOb,WebReqLogObj,AuthLogObj,etc). Hope each and every addition of log object may increase logging threads too.

Still for argument sake, if i use a Single Log Object and push log messages from Multiple Threads, i suppose there must be some mutex lock to prevent writing to the message queue. My Question won't this mutex lock slow down the process, won't it create performance issue ..?

I'm just wondering how Asynchronous loggers work, i can look into the code, that's one way. But Hope the answers will be enlightening to a lot of people.

Comment: You could use a lock-free queue, like `boost::lockfree::queue`.

Comment: Asynchronous loggers are done to do **IO tasks** in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mutex will slow down the process a bit, but if you are logging from multiple threads to the same destination you will need some form of synchronization anyway, since you don't want lines from different threads to be mixed up.

In the end it's a matter of deciding *where* to synchronize, not *if*. With asynchronous logging this happens when the object to be logged is pushed to the queue of the logging thread. In the synchronous case probably at the time the line is written (though it depends on the implementation).

In the first case the time spent inside the mutex will be much shorter and predictable, since no disk flushes happens while in the mutex. This means that you may have *less* performance degradation and better scaling than in the second case (plus the time that you didn't spend writing the actual data, because the other thread is taking care of it).

If you don't have a lot of threads competing for the mutex anyway it won't a problem. I had the chance to write and use an asynchronous logger for a real-time system some time ago, and we reached disk-bandwidth related issues long before sychronization issues.

One downside of asynchronous logging is more memory related: since you need to pass the data to be logged around you need to be careful and avoid unneeded allocations/deallocations.

Answer (score 0):

Mutex lock takes something like 40-60 nanoseconds (if mutex is not locked by another thread) on modern hardware. This is nothing comparing to IO operation which is theoretically can write file to a slow HDD or network drive for a few seconds.

Lock-free is a different thing - in this case you don't even have mutexes. However, there is price for it - you'll have to write a more complicated code.